# Angular Headers not adding to the specific request, when i am having different headers from interceptors

Tags: angular

Unable to add headers for specific request, Interceptor headers are overriding the normal request headers.

Please find the below code.

request code...

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.append('access-token', headerData['access-token']);
        headers = headers.append('client', headerData.client);
        headers = headers.append('uid', headerData.uid);

        console.log(headers);
        let args = {};
        args = {
            password: passwordData.password,
            password_confirmation: passwordData.password_confirmation
        };
        return this.http.put<{ response: any, body: any }>
            (this.getServerPath() + this.options.resetPasswordPath, args, { headers, observe: 'body' });
```

interceptors...

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const username = 'lotvue';
    const password = 'sp4WpwykOyHmIV%X^eCq';
    // debugger;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password),
    });
    const clone =  req.clone({headers});
    console.log(clone);

    return next.handle(clone).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setHeaders`

```
let cloneParams = 
{
   setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(username +':'+ password)}`,
     };

const clone =  req.clone(cloneParams);
```

Comment: @Ayyappa How did you make it work? I am stuck with same kind of problem